# How to pass freerange anything inside a block in a Mocha Expectation (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, rest-client

I'm trying to validate an expectation of a method that has a block being passed to it. Everything works perfectly fine as long as I don't use the *anything* keyword, however I need to use the *anything* keyword so as not to match all parts of the expectation.

**Actual Function Call to be tested.**

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => some_url, :headers => {}.to_json, :payload => {}.to_json)
```

And when I'm testing it out,

**These work (note the usage of *anything*)**

```
RestClient::Request.expects(:execute).with(:method => :post, :url => some_url, :headers => {}.to_json, :payload => {}.to_json)
RestClient::Request.stubs(:execute).with(:method => :post, :url => some_url, :headers => {}.to_json, :payload => {}.to_json)
RestClient::Request.stubs(:execute).with(anything)
```

**This doesn't (note the usage of *anything*)**

```
RestClient::Request.stubs(:execute).with(:method => :post, :url => some_url, :headers => anything, :payload => anything)
```

My problem is that I only want to validate the URL and the method but not the headers and the body of the request. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - In case it helps someone, this is how it is done

Use the ***.with(has_entries( ... ))*** method and pass only the params that are to be validated - avoid passing ***anything*** to the **.with** method.

```
RestClient::Request.expects(:execute).with(has_entries(:method => :post, :url => url))
```